# Alias to add .mylongwebsiteaddress to end of lines in cygwin

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, bash-scripting, bash-alias

I have a server called someserver and a website called mylongwebsiteaddress.com.

Basically I always type $./somecommand.sh someserver.mylongwebsiteaddress.com in cygwin when doing updates to servers.

Is there a way to make an alias so that I can type  somecommand.sh someserver.MY and it will fill in the mylongwebsiteaddress for me at the end of the line and then let me press enter to run the command?

Very noob here, so let me know if that's not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a function to your bashrc

```
webdo(){
    $@ http://www......
}
```

then if you run

```
webdo <command> <args>
```

will run

```
command args http://www......
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the hostname in `$HOSTFILE` (`/etc/hosts` by default), you can use <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> to do a completion on the name.

Answer (score 0):

You could  do

```
 export MY=mylongwebsiteaddress.com 
 somecommand.sh someserver.$MY
```

(note the use of $MY instead of just MY).